# HPE Proliant DL360E Gen8 failing to boot from correct HBA device (H220 and H241)

Tags: boot, windows-server-2019, sas, hp, hp-proliant

So, here's an overview of the problem to hand (Images found at bottom).

A Gen 8 Proliant DL380E with a H220 card managing it's 8x LFF drives in the internal bays.
An MSA60, connected via HP Mini SAS SFF-8644 to SFF-8088, to a H241.

Originally The H220 was in PCI riser slot 2, but after adding the H241/MSA60, refusing to boot from the internal drive bays I assumed it was initialising Slot 1 first (With the H241) and the boot order was being jank.

I did swap the order, power down the MSA60 and do a reinstall of Server 2019 on the DL380E.
All seemed well, install went fine, system booted into windows several times and updated drivers/etc. Turning the MSA60 on post-boot allowed all the drives to be detected within windows fine.

Doing a reboot however informs me that no bootable disk has been found.
Not really sure what I'm missing here to force the H220 to always boot from bay #0, as it's in riser slot 1, set as the primary boot device and seems to work fine when the MSA60 isn't available. I've flashed the latest firmware via SPP already (It behaves the same as it did with stock H241 firmware)

I *believe* the DL380E has an onboard H220 HBA, so I can probably just revert to that, but I've had the physical card in for a while and don't really see that mattering a whole lot. If so (Or if it's another shitty Raid controller) it's disabled in the bios.

I'm going to put on coffee and try snag some pics from ILO remote console.
Any initial thoughts or standout obvious things I've missed? Really scratching my head here on this.

[Bios post with working setup (MSA60 powered down)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrtEN.png)
[Smart Storage doesn't list the H220](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfR7s.png)
[Doing a dianostics report does list H220 though](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUWUj.png)
[The Dianostics Report from Smart Storage](https://pastebin.com/cbZTPhYT)

I can't really see anything here that stands out, the MSA60 is powered down in the current state.